# Fetch existing cron trigger in database using Quartz 2.2.1

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have an update cron trigger function which has input parameters as a DTO object which contains the following parameters

```
 cronTriggerName
 cronTriggerGroupName
 cronExpression
 jobDetailName
 jobDetailGroup
```

I am using an autowired Scheduler object. So I want to fetch the cron trigger object from the above details I would get from request.
I checked the available functions for the scheduler object to find an existing Cron Trigger and all of them require a CronTriggerKey as an argument. I dont have a CronTriggerKey object being passed in from request so I want to fetch an existing CronTrigger using the above parameters. I am using Quartz 2.2.1. Can anyone please help on this?

My current code is as follows:

```
@Autowired
SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory;

public void editTrigger(SchedulerDTO schedulerDto) throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
    if(schedulerDto.getCronTriggerGroup() == null || schedulerDto.getCronTriggerGroup().isEmpty()){
        schedulerDto.setCronTriggerGroup(Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP);
    }

    Trigger updatedTrigger =  TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                            .withIdentity(schedulerDto.getCronTriggerName(), schedulerDto.getCronTriggerGroup())
                            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(schedulerDto.getCronExpression()))
                            .build();

    CronTrigger trigger = cronTrigger.getObject(); // this line of code fetches the 
//cron trigger definition from my xml which is kind of hard coded.
// I want to fetch an existing CronTrigger  in this line from the data I receive from the Scheduler DTO.
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), updatedTrigger);
}

public class SchedulerDTO {

private String cronExpression;
private String cronTriggerName;
private String cronTriggerGroup;
private String jobDetailName;
private String jobDetailGroup;

// setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Add the existing code here, so that we can help

Comment: @javaguy : I have added my code.